# co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException: Error deserializing co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.CreateIndexRequest: Unknown field 'log'

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I want to create an index using elastic 8.9 with a java client.
I have tried

```
var build = new CreateIndexRequest.Builder()
                .index(createYearMonthlyIndex(indexName))
                .withJson(new StringReader(mapToJson(json)))
                .settings(s ->
                        s.numberOfReplicas("2").numberOfShards("3")).build();
```

by specifying "replica" and "shards", but I get this exception:
`co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException: Error deserializing co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.CreateIndexRequest: Unknown field 'executionTime' (JSON path: executionTime) (line no=1, column no=17, offset=16)`

When I try,

```
esClient.index(i -> i
                .index(createYearMonthlyIndex(indexName))
                .withJson(new StringReader(mapToJson(json))));
```

it works correctly. However, if I use CreateIndexRequest it returns the exception -- and I need to set replica and shards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.